# JSON data blinking on refresh, function to avoid drawing new data every time...?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to make a little app using moment.js and the openweatherapi. I am trying to reload my page every 'x' amount of time in order for the time to update. Whenever this happens, my JSON data blinks.. I've seen several questions like this before, but am still struggling..

I was using

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 5000);
```

Here is what my code looks like:

```
 <div id = "data"></div>
   <ul class = "weatherData">
    <li id = "city"></li>
    <li id = "weatherType"></li>
    <li id = "fTemp"></li>
    <li id = "windSpeed"></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


  var api = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?
lat=39.729431&lon=-104.831917&appid=97f35dee6354ab9d2bac7c56a4c4a6fe';

  $.getJSON(api, function(data){
      var weatherType = data.weather[0].description; 
      var city = data.name;
      var windSpeed = data.wind.speed; 
      var kTemp = data.main.temp;
      var fTemp;
      var cTemp;

    fTemp = (kTemp*(9/5)-459.67).toFixed(2);
    cTemp = (kTemp-273).toFixed(2);

    windSpeed = (2.237*(windSpeed)).toFixed(1);


 $('#city').html(city);
 $('#weatherType').html(weatherType);
 $('#fTemp').html(fTemp + " &#8457;");
 $('#windSpeed').html(windSpeed + " mph ");
  });
});


</script>

<script> 

var time = moment().format("h:mm");
var NowMoment = moment().format('LL');
var day = moment().format('dddd');

var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('displayDate');
  eDisplayMoment.innerHTML = NowMoment;


var eDisplayTime = document.getElementById('displayTime');
    eDisplayTime.innerHTML = time; 

document.getElementById('displayDay').innerHTML = day;



</script>
```

Could someone guide me on what to do??

Comment: `JSON data blinks` ? what do you mean?

Comment: Why does page need to be reloaded to update data?

Comment: @Johnny Shellabarger: Here you are doing `window.location.reload()` which actually simulates "Refresh" function in browser, that is why you are seeing the "blink" effect in your browser which is actually full html page might be loading again.

Instead you should create View and ViewModel and just update the data(ViewModel) of your html page(View). You can read very basic tutorial about knockout.js which will do your work within 30 mins of learning. It's very easy and lots of online tutorial available.

let me know if you need any guidance.

Comment: @guest271314 The data changes and needs to be updated. It is getting the current temperature, and current wind speeds. Thanks Om Sao, I will look into this and give you a shout if I need any help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your code in a function called getWeather, and call that from your setInterval. This will re-run the code not the whole page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  var api = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat = 39.729431 & lon = -104.831917 & appid = 97 f35dee6354ab9d2bac7c56a4c4a6fe ';

  function getWeather() {
    $.getJSON(api, function(data) {
      var weatherType = data.weather[0].description;
      var city = data.name;
      var windSpeed = data.wind.speed;
      var kTemp = data.main.temp;
      var fTemp;
      var cTemp;

      fTemp = (kTemp * (9 / 5) - 459.67).toFixed(2);
      cTemp = (kTemp - 273).toFixed(2);

      windSpeed = (2.237 * (windSpeed)).toFixed(1);


      $('#city').html(city);
      $('#weatherType').html(weatherType);
      $('#fTemp').html(fTemp + " &#8457;");
      $('#windSpeed').html(windSpeed + " mph ");
    });
  };



  getWeather();
  setInterval(getWeather, 5000)

});
```

Comment: Sorry typo the last line setInterval(getWeather()... should read getWeather without brackets.

Comment: The code is your original code, all we have done is wrap it with a function, and we are now calling that function in your setInterval.